# How to use a voting regressor to predict a particular instance?

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I created a voting regressor from some regressors like

`voting_regressor = VotingRegressor(estimators=[('xg',xgbregressor),('gb',gradient_boosting_regressor),('et',extra_trees_regressor),('rf',random_forest_regressor)])
voting_regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)`

The regressor predicts well on the test set

```
y_pred = voting_regressor.predict(X_test)
```

but when I try to predict for a particular instance

```
voting_regressor.predict(X_test.iloc[0].values.reshape(1,-1))
```

it shows following error

> ValueError: feature_names mismatch: ['yearpublished', 'minplayers', 'maxplayers', 'playingtime', 'minplaytime', 'maxplaytime', 'minage', 'users_rated', 'total_owners', 'total_traders', 'total_wanters', 'total_wishers', 'total_comments', 'total_weights', 'average_weight'] ['f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9', 'f10', 'f11', 'f12', 'f13', 'f14']
>   expected users_rated, total_wishers, yearpublished, maxplayers, maxplaytime, total_owners, total_weights, average_weight, minplaytime, total_wanters, total_traders, playingtime, minage, total_comments, minplayers in input data
>   training data did not have the following fields: f9, f3, f13, f0, f8, f4, f14, f5, f2, f6, f12, f11, f7, f10, f1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `pandas.Series` instead of `pandas.DataFrame` when using `iloc`, when names of columns are required as indicated by error.

If you want to return dataframe with one example you can wrap it with another list like this:

```
voting_regressor.predict(X_test.iloc[[0]])
```

This way names of columns are preserved

You could specify many examples as well simply by using `[0, 1, 2, 3]`.